# Python2.7 script to check powershell version, .net version and firmware version

Tags: python, .net, python-3.x, python-2.7, powershell

How to check powershell version, .net version and firmware version using python in windows(Python 2.7 code to check the versions)?

I have seen some powershell code to find versions, but am not able to figure out how to use Python to find the version. It will be really helpful if someone can help me out here.

Comment: I literally just googled "python check dotnet version": http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578143-a-small-python-script-to-detect-net-framwork-versi/

Comment: I have seen this for .net version but got a bit confused. So thought if there was a simpler way to find the version. Plus I also need help with powershell and firmware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For .net version and firmware version you can refer to @Ofer Sadan's comment. In order to check the powershell version, vou ca ncreate a `check_powershell.py` file and write:

```
import os
print (os.system('powershell.exe $PSVersionTable'))
```

Then execute it as usual (i.e. `python check_powershell.py`).

**[UPDATE]**
According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed), you can check the `.net` version by opening the following registry sub-key. The installed versions will be listed under the NDP subkey. In code:

```
import os
print (os.system('powershell.exe Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry:: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP '))
```

Comment: upvoted this answer for using the command but I think he will need it as a variable and not just printed out

Comment: Hi I am getting this when I tried executing it
PSVersionTable : The term 'PSVersionTable' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ PSVersionTable
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (PSVersionTable:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Hi @OferSadan. Thanks for the upvote! It's not clear by the OP's question whether he needs it in a variable or not. I had it printed because I thought he just wanted to see the powershell version.

Comment: I think it's `$PSVersionTable`. Also edited the answer.

Comment: how to check the .net version and firmware ...... the link that @OferSadan gave..... I have seen that, but got confused .... Is there any simpler way to check the version

Comment: Please see updated answer. I put together a quick solution but I haven't tested it.

Comment: @kingJulian hi how do I access the values from the the PSVersionTable sfter I assin it to I variable??? I was trying to use pandas but was not able to do so.

Comment: What is the type of your variable? You can see this by using `type(var)` where var is the name of your variable.